# How to Add Controller in Angular 2 like Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am Using Angular 2, I want to Add new Controller to my HTML File, please help and let me know any Solution.

here is some code I tried

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.firstName = "John";

    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
```

Comment: Controllers are not there with angular2

Comment: you have to make logic in class (.ts) there is no controller in angular2

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.firstName = "John";

$scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
```

same logic for anguilar2 is like

```
export class myCtrl {
  firstName: string = "John";
  lastName : string = "Doe";

  constructor(){}
};
```

there is no controller in angular2 for same you have to make logic in the class which is being exported in order to use in the module